# password digest can't be blank error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

my admin/views/parents/new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for ([:admin, @parent]) do |f| %>
  <% if @parent.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% @parent.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<%= f.label :username %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :username %> <br/>
<%= f.password_field :password %> <br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

model models/parent.rb

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    belongs_to :student
end
```

Controller: admin/controllers/parents_controller.erb

```
 def new
    @parent = Parent.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @parent = Parent.create(params[:create])
        if @parent.save
            redirect_to "admin"
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
  end
```

When I press submit, i am getting error, `password digest can't be blank` but password field is filled

Answer (score 0):

params[:create]
i think it should be params[:parent]